# How to highlight the next 15 days right from the current day with a different color shade in ngx-bootstrap datepicker component

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using ngx-bootstrap date-picker component in my application.
There is a requirement where in based on the current date the next 15 days need to be highlighted with a different color shade along with the selected day highlight.

ngx-bootstrap: v2.0.2
Angular: v4.2.4